# jquery ignoring code after added by .append

Tags: jquery

Hi I am currently using the .append function to add a row from a ajax response, however the delete function is ignoring the newly created record. You can see this working live at http://booking.everythingcreative.co.uk/index2.php. I can't see where I'm going wrong

Insert row code:

```
var record =    '<tr id="customer_'+ outcome['id'] +'">\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['firstname'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['surname'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['email'] +'</td>\
                                    <td>'+ outcome['training'] +'</td>\
                                    <td><a class="confirmation button_live" href="tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id='+ outcome['id'] +'&version=email">Send Invitation</a></td>\
                                    <td><a class="confirmation button_live" href="tcpdf/PDF/testPDF.php?id='+ outcome['id'] +'&version=download">Download</a></td>\
                                    <td>???????</td>\
                                    <td><a href="#" id="delete_'+ outcome['id'] +'" class="button_delete">Remove</a></td>';
                    $(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(record);
```

Delete code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".global_table .button_delete", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var clickedID = this.id.split('_'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
         var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
         var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

        $('#customer_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class
        $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "assets/scripts/ajax.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                $('#customer_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });
```

As you can see the `customer_id`is being created with the new row so I don't know why the `$('#customer_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();` isn't responding

Comment: Worked fine for me in Chrome. It did have layout issues on creation of the new row, but a refresh cleared it up. The row deleted and faded out nicely.

Comment: sorry correction http://booking.everythythingcreative.co.uk/index2.php

Comment: For me, latter link not responding.

Comment: nope just tried it in those two browsers, the delete button works fine on existing rows but not when you try to delete a row you've just created without refreshing the browser...only the delete button disappears, but when you refresh the PHP code has run correctly and deleted the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new record is created, is added in two locations:

```
$(".global_table tr:nth-last-child(2)").after(record);
```

There are two tables with the "global_table" class and the first table is hidden.
When this code is executed:

```
$('#customer_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
```

only the first element is selected (which is hidden) and the second remains visible.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand, can you please elaborate

Comment: O sorry I get it! I was being stupid, really simple fix, can't believe I didn't see it